# Requesting files from another parent directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say that we have a server running multiple virtual hosts. Somefiles and directories are shared amongst these virtual hosts, such as JS-, HTML-, and some PHP-files. I want to prevent having to make a new copy of these files every single time we add a new virtual host, since it would make it hard to keep the files up to date. So what I want to do is to  put these shared files in another parent directory i.e. /var/www/shared_files/.
So when one of the shared files is requested i.e. http://example.com/scripts/gallery.js I want  to get the file located in /var/www/shared_files/gallery.js instead of /var/www/xxx/gallery.js.

The first solution I found for this problem was a htaccess solution:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery.js ../shared_files/gallery.js
```

Which only works as long as all the files is requested via the servers IP, i.e. http://11.11.0.111/xxx/gallery.js.

The second solution is a PHP solution:

```
if(* is 404 *)
{
    if(file_exists("/var/www/shared_files/* the requested file name *"))
    {
        if(strpos(* the requested file name *, ".js") !== false)
            header("Content-type: text/javascript");

        require_once("/var/www/shared_files/* the requested file name *");
        die();
    }
}
```

This dosnt seem like a good solution in the long run so do anyone know of a better solution for this?

- Edited after TerryE's comment

Comment: I assume that you mean virtual ***hosts*** and not virtual ***servers*** since separate VMs maintain separate address spaces.

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your shared files reside in a location outside the VirtualHost, you should access them via an own domain/subdomain.

So you should link http://shared.example.com/gallery.js instead (where shared.example.com is a subdomain, that links to your shared files folder).

Comment: +1.  Putting shared resources in a resource only domain is a common practice, not only for normalisation of resource pools, but also there may be some performance benefits as many browsers will only open two HTTP 1.1 data streams per source host.